# Case Study in java

Tags: java

Could anyone provide me information where I can find the case study for java coding and design practice.

Basically looking for a case studies which resemble to the real time application like pet Store application, flight search application.

Comment: sounds like homework. more details, on what you want to accomplish here, is required.

Comment: Hi Nishant, I am looking to learn the java concepts like multi thread, collections from a business point of view. Like for a given scenario what collection class to use.

Comment: Something worth nothing is that "real time" has a specific meaning and is not the same real world.  The Pet Store application isn't real-time and possibly not that close to a real-world application either. ;)

Comment: @Peter- I mean case studies which will help me the to learn how to apply the java concepts for best result.

Comment: If you want real world code, I suggest you look at some of the popular open source packages. e.g. http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/ http://java-sources.net/ This should ive you a few million lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

[The Design Patterns Java Companion](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=The+Design+Patterns+Java++Companion) teaches good design practices with the help of small Java applications. (Not sure if the free online copy of this book is legal or not).